# Images appearing too dark

Tags: css, wordpress, opacity

Header images on this site I'm building are appearing too dark - I can't see any opacity is being applied - http://www.stayinblackpool.co.uk/ - any ideas what could be causing this?

Tried to make opacity 1.0

Comment: give opacity to image it will be light after it

Comment: There is a black overlay over the image... `<div class="overlay"></div>`. You have to set the opacity of the overlay to `0.1` or just remove the entire div.

Comment: Just change `background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);` to `background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);` in `overlay` css will resolve your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opacity is being applied - in the form of background alpha key. Here is your markup:

```
<div class="featured-image">    
    <img src="http://www.stayinblackpool.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/header3.jpg">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="grid-mid">
            <h1 class="page-title">Serviced Holiday Apartments in North Shore, Blackpool</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's associated CSS:

```
.overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

If you notice background has rgba, 0.5 is causing 50% opacity. I would remove the background attribute completely.